# back before sort tableview javafx

Tags: javafx

I have a TableView and I have 2 buttons. The first button sort the tableView DESCENDING, and I would like that the second button back to the initial tableView, before that the tableView sorted.

It's possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: As I know the (only?) solution is to use `SortedList`: http://fxexperience.com/2013/08/returning-a-tableview-back-to-an-unsorted-state-in-javafx-8-0/

Comment: How do you sort the table? Using the `TableView`'s sorting mechanism, `SortedList` or something else?

Comment: I have this : `tableColumnPrix.setSortType(TableColumn.SortType.DESCENDING);
tableViewArticle.getSortOrder().add(tableColumnPrix);`

Comment: Are you trying to sort a column or all columns of the tableview?

Comment: With my two line code, the button sort all row of my tableView with a "tableColumnPrix" DESCENDING.